# Unable to change site's URL in Wordpress plugin.

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

My host is nearlyfreespeech.org. I contacted them with this message:

"My problem is, when you navigate thru the menu on my site and click on the various links, I need the navigation bar to say http://www.paulaneeley.com/education-and-experience/, instead of paulaneeley.nfshost.com/education-and-experience/. How do I change all the links from the subpages I made on my site from paulaneeley.nfshost.com/etc to paulaneeley.com/etc ?"

And they responded:

"Take a look in the WordPress dashboard at the settings page. Probably one of these settings isn't using your own domain:
WordPress Address (URL)
Site Address (URL)
Once you find and fix that (so neither of them uses the paulaneeley.nfshost.com addres, this problem will likely disappear. "

So I changed the site's address to paulaneeley.com. I then got this error:

```
Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/f5/paulaneeley/:/nfsn/apps/php53/lib/php/:/nfsn/apps/php5/lib/php/:/nfsn/apps/php/lib/php/) 
in /f5/paulaneeley/public/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 133

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
/f5/paulaneeley/public/wp-admin/includes/misc.php:133) 
in /f5/paulaneeley/public/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
```

I then tried to navigate back to my dashboard and I couldn't access it anymore! My browser gave me this error:

```
too many redirects occurred trying to open "http://paulaneeley.nfshost.com/wp-admin/".     
This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which is then 
redirected to open the original page.
```

I then read this article:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

And tried both the functions.php method and the phpmyadmin method to return back to the original paulaneeley.nfshost.com, which I believe I both did correctly. My site works fine, but I still get an error message when I try to access my dashboard. At the least, I would like to get my dashboard back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem, you will need to change the setting of your site's database where the root of your domain is found. You can do this by running a mysql update command.

Then, you can change your .htaccess setting.

Another way is to just install it all over again. Just make sure you have a backup of your data, media, and template. This time, make sure that you install it from your domain http://www.paulaneeley.com. Or http://paulaneeley.com. You can only choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've done all the things right, but the nameservers of nearlyfreespeech are stil not forwarding users to your site.

Test for yourself:

http://www.paulaneeley.com, opens just fine but when you remove a `www.` prefix, the site doesn't opens. A simple ping test to http://paulaneeley.com reveals that nearlyfreespeech's name servers do not have a record for http://paulaneeley.com. Ping returns with an error `Ping request could not find host paulaneeley.com. Please check the name and try
again.` Indicating there are no DNS records for http://paulaneeley.com.

So, contact them again, and this time tell them to fix this by registering http://paulaneeley.com in their nameservers. And if they ask for money, don't pay them any, because http://paulaneeley.com and http://www.paulaneeley.com are the same sites and `www.` doesn't mean anything that they should charge for.

And best of luck for your business, maybe one day I'll drop by and will get my hair styled, your work seems pretty cool. :)

And here's your login page,

http://paulaneeley.nfshost.com/wp-login.php
http://www.paulaneeley.com/wp-login.php

Apparently, you've edited your `.htaccess` file(by mistake?) which used to redirect `http://www.paulaneeley.com/wp-login/` to `http://www.paulaneeley.com/wp-login.php`